# Storage account is of unsupported type 'Blob-Only/ZRS'. Supported types are 'General Purpose'

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-webjobs, azure-storage-account

I am trying to run a WebJob which has AzureWebJobsDashboard and AzureWebJobsStorage configured to use a storage account that is general purpose. However I am receiving this error that the storage account is of unsupported type 'Blob-Only/ZRS' even though the storage account is configured to be LRS and general purpose.

What may be the issue?

[image: Storage Account]

Answer (score 0):

> Storage account is of unsupported type 'Blob-Only/ZRS'. Supported types are 'General Purpose'

ZRS currently supports **standard general-purpose v2 account types**, while your Tier is Premium. For more information about storage account types, see [Azure storage account overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-introduction#types-of-storage-accounts).

Additionally fill the `AzureWebJobsDashboard` and `AzureWebJobsStorage` connection strings with the General Purpose storage account's connection string at the beginning of your `app.settings` of your WebJob.

Comment: You are saying ZRS only supports standard account types not premium, but the storage account is not using ZRS. It is using LRS replication. Also what do you mean by the General Purpose storage account?